# Setting a button

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 buttons. One is "add". The other is "cancel". In the cancel button action, I want to write that until the add method is not called, this button do nothing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable the cancel button initially. Then, in the add action listener, enable the cancel button.

```
JButton add = new JButton("Add");
JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

cancel.setEnabled(false);

// Then something along these lines...
add.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cancel.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

NOTE: I haven't used Swing in a while, so my syntax could be off...

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your app, you could call `setEnabled(false)` on your cancel `JButton`. Then in your handler for your add `JButton`, you could call `setEnabled(true)` on the cancel `JButton`. Here is a [demo from Sun's Swing Tutorial for disabling/enabling JButtons](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton) (source code available at link).